# One Symfony 2.0 Controller-Action with two different templates

Tags: templates, view, symfony, twig

Is it possible to assign two different templates to an action in Symfony 2.0? In the following code, I wanna render the IF part and ELSE part with two different template.

```
 /**
 *
 * @Route("/", name="search")
 * @Template("Bundle:Search:search.html.twig")
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    if ($searchText == null) {

        return array('form' => $form->createView(), 'form2' => $form2->createView());

    } else {

        return array('applicants' => $appCount, 'pagination' => $pagination, 'form' => $form->createView(),'form2' => $form2->createView());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that with the `@Template` annotation, but you can render each manually:

```php
if ($someCondition) {
    return $this->render('Bundle:Controller:template.html.twig', array(
        'some' => $thing,
    );
}

return $this->render('Bundle:Controller:another.html.twig', array(
    'another' => $thing,
);
```